# How can I group rows by DateTime if the values are almost the same?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

How can I group rows if the different time between on field and other field in other row almost the same?

For example:

```
GUID - No    - sDateTime            - eDateTime           - Name  
------------------------------------------------------------------    
0000 - 01    - 2013-02-02 08:00:00  - 2013-02-02 08:40:00 - A 
0000 - 02    - 2013-02-02 08:45:00  - 2013-02-02 09:45:00 - A 
0000 - 03    - 2013-02-02 11:30:00  - 2013-02-02 12:00:00 - A 
0000 - 04    - 2013-02-02 09:55:00  - 2013-02-02 11:00:00 - A   
0000 - 05    - 2013-02-02 11:05:00  - 2013-02-02 12:30:00 - B
```

How can I get `sDateTime` from row with `eDateTime` from other row if the different not more than 10 minutes?

```
GUID - No      - SDateTime            - EDateTime (From other row) - Name  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
0000 -01,02,04 - 2013-02-02 08:00:00  - **2013-02-02 11:00:00**    - A 
0000 - 03      - 2013-02-02 11:30:00  - 2013-02-02 12:00:00        - A
0000 - 05      - 2013-02-02 11:05:00  - 2013-02-02 12:30:00        - B
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: @NitinMidha SQL Server 2008 Express Edition

Comment: Also why 05 is not combined with 01,02 and 04? I think it satisfies the criteria of 10 Mins, if i understand correctly ..

Comment: It is grouped within under similar name?

Comment: Because the SDateTime = 11:30 and the nearest value of EDateTime with same Name is 11:00, so the different is more than 10 minutes.

Comment: sorry i can't seem to understand what you're asking. However, i suggest that you try joining to the other table by a date range. for example "inner join table2 on table2.startdate between DATEADD(minute, -10, table1.enddate) and DATEADD(minute,10, table1.enddate)

Comment: @elvis i want to group all records that contain sDateTime Different by 10 minutes or less from eDateTime from another record, If first record is start at 10:00 and finish at 11:15 and other record is start at 11:25, the two records should be one record that start at 10:00 and finish at 11:25 if the name in both records is same , i hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No cursors here but this is still a loop over rows using a recursive CTE to figure out what rows should be grouped together. The temp table `#T` is there to hold the `ID` that connects rows to each other. It could have been done without the temp table but for performance reasons it is better to do it with a temp table instead of having another CTE as the source for the recursive CTE.

In the final query I use the `for xml path` trick to concatenate the values from `No`. That means that the CTE `C` is used a second time so it will be executed twice. You might want to turn that CTE to a temp table as well to avoid that.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60c03/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  GUID varchar(4),
  No varchar(2),
  sDateTime datetime,
  eDateTime datetime,
  Name varchar(1)
);

insert into YourTable values
('0000', '01', '2013-02-02 08:00:00', '2013-02-02 08:40:00', 'A'),
('0000', '02', '2013-02-02 08:45:00', '2013-02-02 09:45:00', 'A'),
('0000', '03', '2013-02-02 11:30:00', '2013-02-02 12:00:00', 'A'),
('0000', '04', '2013-02-02 09:55:00', '2013-02-02 11:00:00', 'A'),
('0000', '05', '2013-02-02 11:05:00', '2013-02-02 12:30:00', 'B');
```

**Query 1**:

```
create table #T
(
  ID int,
  GUID varchar(4),
  No varchar(2),
  sDateTime datetime,
  eDateTime datetime,
  Name varchar(1),
  primary key(ID, GUID, Name)
);

insert into #T(ID, GUID, No, sDateTime, eDateTime, Name)
select row_number() over(partition by GUID, Name order by sDateTime),
       GUID, No, sDateTime, eDateTime, Name
from YourTable;

with C as
(
  select T.ID, T.GUID, T.No, T.sDateTime, T.eDateTime, T.Name, 1 as Grp
  from #T as T
  where T.ID = 1
  union all
  select T.ID, T.GUID, T.No, T.sDateTime, T.eDateTime, T.Name, 
         C.Grp + case when datediff(minute, C.eDateTime, T.sDateTime) > 10 
                   then 1 
                   else 0 
                 end
  from #T as T
    inner join C 
      on T.ID = C.ID + 1 and
         T.Name = C.Name and
         T.GUID = C.GUID
)
select C.GUID,
       (
       select ','+C2.No
       from C as C2
       where C.GUID = C2.GUID and
             C.Name = C2.Name and
             C.Grp = C2.Grp
       order by C2.No
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as No,
       min(C.sDateTime) as sDateTime,
       max(C.eDateTime) as eDateTime,
       C.Name
from C
group by C.GUID, C.Name, C.Grp

drop table #T;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60c03/3/0)**:

```
| GUID |       NO |                       SDATETIME |                       EDATETIME | NAME |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0000 | 01,02,04 | February, 02 2013 08:00:00+0000 | February, 02 2013 11:00:00+0000 |    A |
| 0000 |       03 | February, 02 2013 11:30:00+0000 | February, 02 2013 12:00:00+0000 |    A |
| 0000 |       05 | February, 02 2013 11:05:00+0000 | February, 02 2013 12:30:00+0000 |    B |
```

Just for fun, a SQL Server 2012 version.

```
with CMinDiff as
(
  select GUID, No, sDateTime, eDateTime, Name, 
         case when datediff(minute, 
                            coalesce(lag(eDateTime) over(partition by GUID, Name 
                                                         order by eDateTime), 
                                     sDateTime), 
                            sDateTime) <= 10 
           then 0 
           else 1 
         end as MinDiff
  from YourTable
), CSumMinDiff as
(
  select GUID, No, sDateTime, eDateTime, Name, 
         sum(MinDiff) over(partition by GUID, Name 
                           order by sDateTime 
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Grp
  from CMinDiff
)
select C.GUID,
       (
       select ','+C2.No
       from CSumMinDiff as C2
       where C.GUID = C2.GUID and
             C.Name = C2.Name and
             C.Grp = C2.Grp
       order by C2.No
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as No,
       min(C.sDateTime) as sDateTime,
       max(C.eDateTime) as eDateTime,
       C.Name
from CSumMinDiff as C
group by C.GUID, C.Name, C.Grp
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to perform this without a cursor, maybe somebody smarter can come up with a solution that does not include cursors, but this is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    [GUID] VARCHAR(4),
    [No] VARCHAR(2),
    [sDateTime] DATETIME,
    [eDateTime] DATETIME,
    [Name] VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO [MyTable]
([GUID], [No], [sDateTime], [eDateTime], [Name])
VALUES
('0000', '01', '2013-02-02 08:00:00', '2013-02-02 08:40:00', 'A'),
('0000', '02', '2013-02-02 08:45:00', '2013-02-02 09:45:00', 'A'),
('0000', '03', '2013-02-02 11:30:00', '2013-02-02 12:00:00', 'A'),
('0000', '04', '2013-02-02 09:55:00', '2013-02-02 11:00:00', 'A'),
('0000', '05', '2013-02-02 11:05:00', '2013-02-02 12:30:00', 'B')

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE 
(
    [GUID] VARCHAR(4),
    [No] VARCHAR(100),
    [sDateTime] DATETIME,
    [eDateTime] VARCHAR(100),
    [Name] VARCHAR(1)
)

DECLARE [MyCursor] CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [GUID], [No], [sDateTime], [eDateTime], [Name]
FROM [MyTable]
ORDER BY [Name], [sDateTime];

DECLARE @GUID AS VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @No AS VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @sDateTime AS DATETIME
DECLARE @eDateTime AS DATETIME
DECLARE @Name AS VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @OldName AS VARCHAR(1)
SET @OldName = ''
DECLARE @MergedNo AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @MergedNo = NULL
DECLARE @sOldDateTime AS DATETIME
DECLARE @eOldDateTime AS DATETIME

OPEN [MyCursor]
FETCH NEXT FROM [MyCursor] 
INTO @GUID, @No, @sDateTime, @eDateTime, @Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF (@OldName = '')
    BEGIN
        SET @sOldDateTime = @sDateTime
        SET @OldName = @Name
    END
    ELSE IF (@OldName <> @Name OR DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @eOldDateTime, @sDateTime) > 10)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @MyTable
        ([GUID], [No], [sDateTime], [eDateTime], [Name])
        VALUES
        (@GUID, @MergedNo, @sOldDateTime, CASE WHEN @MergedNo LIKE '%,%' THEN '**' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @eOldDateTime, 20) + '**' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @eOldDateTime, 20) END, @Name)

        SET @sOldDateTime = @sDateTime 
        SET @OldName = @Name
        SET @MergedNo = NULL
    END

    SET @MergedNo = COALESCE(@MergedNo + ', ', '') + @No
    SET @eOldDateTime = @eDateTime

    FETCH NEXT FROM [MyCursor] 
    INTO @GUID, @No, @sDateTime, @eDateTime, @Name
END 
CLOSE [MyCursor];
DEALLOCATE [MyCursor];

IF (@OldName <> '')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @MyTable
    ([GUID], [No], [sDateTime], [eDateTime], [Name])
    VALUES
    (@GUID, @MergedNo, @sOldDateTime, CASE WHEN @MergedNo LIKE '%,%' THEN '**' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @eOldDateTime, 20) + '**' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @eOldDateTime, 20) END, @Name)
END

SELECT *
FROM @MyTable

DROP TABLE [MyTable]
```